# pandas keep numerical part

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, numeric

I have a set of data like:

```
        0       1 
0  type 1  type 2
1  type 3  type 4
```

How can I transfer it to:

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

perfer using `apply`or `transform` function

Comment: What's more, How can I transfer `False` to 0 and `True` to 1.

Answer (score 3):

***Option 1***

```
df.stack().str.replace('type ', '').unstack()
```

***Option 2***

```
df.stack().str.split().str[-1].unstack()
```

***Option 3***

```
# pandas version 0.18.1 +
df.stack().str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).unstack()

# pandas version 0.18.0 or prior
df.stack().str.extract('(\d+)').unstack()
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

***conclusion*** @jezreal's is best.  no loops and no stacking.

***code***

***20,000 by 200***

```
df_ = df.copy()

df = pd.concat([df_ for _ in range(10000)], ignore_index=True)
df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(100)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Comment: would be interested to see if there is any difference without the `astype()`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('type ','').astype(int))
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

remove the `.astype(int)` if you don't need to convert to int

Answer (score 3):

Yoou can use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
print (df.replace({'type ': ''}, regex=True))
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `applymap` and a regex (`import re`):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: re.search(r'.*(\d+)', x).group(1))
```

If you want the digits as integers:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(re.search(r'.*(\d+)', x).group(1)))
```

This will work even if you have other text instead of `type`, and only with integers (ie `'type 1.2'` will break this code), so you will have to adapt it.

Also note that this code is bound to fail if no number is found (ie `'type'`). You may want to create a function that can handle these errors instead of the `lambda`:

```
def extract_digit(x):
     try:
         return int(re.search(r'.*(\d+)', x).group(1))
     except (ValueError, AttributeError):
         # return the existing value
         return x

df = df.applymap(lambda x: extract_digit(x))
```